# How to get all dates of the week based on week number using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell 7.x and want to create an array of dates in a week based on the weeknumber. I'm able to generate the array and find the whole week dates but how can I get the date values returned in the output?

I have used [System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime([Int32] year,[Int32] week number,[DayOfWeek]:Monday), to fetch the days of the week. Is there a better and optimal way to fetch all the dates in the array based on the week number?

Here's the code below:

```
function fetchWeekDates {
    $output = @{ Monday =[System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime(2022,1,[DayOfWeek]::Monday)}
    $output += @{ Tuesday=[System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime(2022,1,[DayOfWeek]::Tuesday)}
    $output += @{ Wednesday =[System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime(2022,1,[DayOfWeek]::Wednesday)}
    .
    .
    .
    $output += @{ Sunday =[System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime(2022,1,[DayOfWeek]::Sunday)}

    return $output
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
Output
------- 
01-03-2022
01-04-2022
01-05-2022
01-06-2022
01-07-2022
01-08-2022
01-09-2022
```

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://getps.dev/blog/get-weekinfo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function accepts a week number, and optionally a year (defaults to the current) and the day of the week that is considered the start of a week (defaults to Monday), and outputs `[datetime]` instances representing all days in that week.

```bash
function Get-DatesInWeekNumber {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [int] $WeekNumber,
    [int] $Year = (Get-Date).Year,
    [DayOfWeek] $FirstDayOfWeek = 'Monday'
  )
  $date = [Globalization.ISOWeek]::ToDateTime($Year, $WeekNumber, $FirstDayOfWeek)
  0..6 | ForEach-Object { $date.AddDays($_) }
}
```

Note the use of the [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) type's [`.AddDays()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.AddDays) method.

Sample call, which formats the `[datetime]` instances as desired:

```bash
Get-DatesInWeekNumber -WeekNumber 1 -Year 2022 |
  ForEach-Object ToString MM-dd-yyyy
```

This produces the output as shown in your question.